# pubtator format using python

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I have a project to make ***DNorm*** software runs specific file format (Pubtator). I have XML file and I want to change it to pubtator format using python to make it readable for DNorm.

Pubtator file contains many blocks. The format of each Pubtator block is the following:
PMID|t|ArticleTitle
PMID|a|AbstractText

Where ***PMID, ArticleTitle and AbstractText*** are tags in XML blocks, while 't' and 'a' are constant for each time we create new block.

I want to help how to use Python to retrieve XML tags values and store it in new file in Pubtator format. any example code or resource?

Answer (score 0):

after doing some google-research it seemed that there is no standard Pubtator parser. So I suggest you study the text pattern thoroughly and build a local standard for your purpose. But you can refer to [this](https://github.com/ashishbaghudana/PubTator2Anndoc) for your reference. It might help you understand Pubtator better.